# Is there a way to return the size calculated by constraints in the sizeForItemAt UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I'm overriding the sizeForItemAt method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. What I'd like to do is only calculate the size if I'm in a certain section, and fall back to the default flow layout behaviour for the other sections.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about it, as I'm not subclassing I can't just use the super class implementation.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I wanted to use `systemLayoutSizeFitting` as demonstrated below, but the cell isn't created when `sizeForItemAt` is called.

```swift
guard indexPath.section == sectionNumber else {
  // This always returns nil as the cell hasn't been created when sizeForItemAt runs
  guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
    return .zero
  }

  return cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
}

return someCalculatedCGSize
```

I've tried creating my own layout subclass but I run into the same issues, I have two full width cells which auto layout provides constraints for and then a grid layout below which I manually calculate sizes for. So I'd like to fall back to my constraints providing the size for the first two cells.